# Unable to get form input to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am newbie to Javascript... and I am unable to get from input to js variable, I referred to the questions asked here before still I unable to get the information. My code is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS </title>
<body>

    <form>
    <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h1 id="TotalAmout"></h1>
    <script>
        function calc() {
    var amt = document.getElementById("amount").value;

    document.getElementById("TotalAmount").innerHTML = amt;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo. Is that the issue? `<h1 id="TotalAmout"></h1>` says amout instead of amount.

Comment: typo is there and one more problem is there calc is defined after its calling `onclick`. Define script in `head`

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! I am trying to build calculator to calculate Total Amount with interest rate...., I will continue building. Thank you so much! @Marnix

Comment: @Pardeep Dhingra It works before the </body> tag too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Typo in H1 `TotalAmout` should be `TotalAmount`
2. Calc should be defined before calling it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq4f5uje/)

   ```
   <head>
     function calc() {
       var amt = document.getElementById("amount").value;
       document.getElementById("TotalAmount").innerHTML = amt;
     }
   </head> 
   <body>
     <form>
       <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
       <button type="button" onclick="javascript:calc()">Submit</button>
     </form>
    <h1 id="TotalAmount"></h1>
   </body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your H1's ID. It should probably match the `TotalAmount` in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
<button type="button" onclick="calc();return false">Submit</button>
</form>

<h1 id="TotalAmout"></h1>
<script>
    function calc() {
var amt = $("#amount").val();

$("TotalAmount").html(amt);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is that Jquery or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- typo in "TotalAmout" and "TotalAmount"
- function needs to be defined prior to calling it

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/zLguL6fu/:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
  <button type="button" onclick="calc(); return false;">Submit</button>
</form>
<h1 id="TotalAmount"></h1>

function calc() {
   var amt = document.getElementById("amount").value;

   document.getElementById("TotalAmount").innerHTML = amt;
 }
```

Comment: Preventing the form to be executed. Not necessary here as there's no method attribute, but anyway...

Answer (score 0):

please use this code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS </title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
    <input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Amount">
    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <h1 id="TotalAmout"></h1>
    <script>
        function calc() {
            var amt = $("#amount").val();
            $("#TotalAmout").html(amt);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and you also required add jquery js in head